# Is there any way to share JavaScript code between Tizen projects?

Tags: eclipse, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm using the Tizen IDE for Wearable (which is based on Eclipse), and have a couple of closely-related Gear apps. There's a lot of JavaScript (and CSS) in common between the two, so I'm looking to create something like a "library project" - one that contains the common js/css, and which both of my apps can reference.

I've explored every way I can think of doing this, however, and none has worked out. Approaches based on linked folders fail to build (with a java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified), while those using Eclipse's build path simply don't include the referenced files in the output .wgt.

DRY is such a basic programming practice that I can't believe there's no way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) for the subproject (or a similar concept if you use something else for versioning, eg. [mercurial subrepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) or [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Use git submodules/mercurial subrepositories as Paul S has suggested.

Following the best practises on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository  you would probably end up using 3 repos for your gear app:

1. A repository containing the app related code
2. One repo containg the "library" aka the commmon css/js
3. One thin "shell" repo that only contains the "app" and the "library" repository

Using this approach you can develop the app and the library code independently.

If the library version evolves your shell repo still tracks the version that is guaranteed to work with your app repo as long as you don't decide to upgrade the lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to New/File then select advanced and mark "Link to file in the file system"
it will create new file in your project, but in fact it will point to existing file. 
You can go to project properties/resource/linked resources to check the list.